# Problem with decoding Base64 bitmap that sent to server via http request

Tags: android, spring, retrofit2

We are trying to call a post request via HTTP call in android, the library that we are using is Retrofit.
First of all, we encode our Bitmap image to base64 with the following code.

```
public static String toBase64(Bitmap bitmap) {
    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, outputStream);

    return Base64.encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray(), Base64.DEFAULT);
}
```

And then we send our data using Retrofit to our server.
Our backend is written both with Spring and Flask frameworks and both servers behave exactly the same.

We've tried to debug and find the problem. We found that some weird character is added to the request's body sometimes. It is not persistent but sometimes we got errors on server side.
As you can see in the [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ddXHB.jpg) some characters are replaced with some weird characters that aren't in UTF-8 charset. Also, we have this issue on iOS platforms too and I should mention that the size of the image is around 1MB.

The 'Content-Type' header is set correctly like content-type: application/json; UTF-8.

I would really appreciate it if someone could help.

Comment: Which `Base64` class are you using? Have you tried the JDK default version? `Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(outputStream.toByteArray());`? Instead of some other version?

Comment: `First of all, we encode our Bitmap image to base64` No. That encodes base64 a jpg file/image. A bad idea to encode base64 as you have to transfer 30 % more bytes. Upload the original.

Comment: `The 'Content-Type' header is set correctly like content-type: application/json; UTF-8.` ?? But then you are not uploading a base64 string. What is the connection between json and your base64?